# Get the global caret position on screen

Tags: java, position, hook, global, caret

I'm writing an application that needs to give context-sensitive help by displaying pop-up windows in which you can continue to interact in the data.

It is very similar to the work of a text editor Eclipse, but the difference is that this program works in the background and analyzes the entered text in all programs mainly for postal correspondence sort of thing.

For the analysis of the keyboard I use `JNativeHook`, but faced with such a problem that I can't determine the position of the cursor carriage globally.

What do I need to use as the library?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with native APIs.  You _might_ be able to get the focused window and then possibly a focused area of that window, but I am not sure how far you can get cross-platform.

Comment: my prog must be at background. :(

Comment: I am assuming you want to find the position of the input carrot not the mouse pointer?  If I understood you correctly, you can use JNA and the Windows function [GetCaretPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648402(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the position.  There might be similar API's for OS X and Linux but I don't have time to dig for them right now.